# Elastic Search not generating user credentials during the first run

Tags: elasticsearch

I have downloaded Elastic-Search from the following URL: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-8-4-0.
I need to use the version 8.4, but it keeps giving me this error:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEfr4.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC4HB.png)

I don't know what am I doing wrong, I just unzipped the file, and put it in my "C:\Program Files\Elastic". It was previously running without any issue, if you could help, please and thank you!

I tried removing it and reinstalling it a couple of times but it didn't work

Comment: Please try to run this command and add the output in the question

`bin\elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic`

Comment: @MusabDogan It did not work! https://i.imgur.com/Rx0iLGO.png

Comment: The cluster status is RED, there is a problem with security-7 index shards. You need to understand why it's not these shards is not allocated. If you can share full elasticsearch logs I can help you

Comment: @MusabDogan but I just installed it, how could there be a problem, sorry I dont know much regarding elastic search, I'm just installing it so that It could work with a different application, but is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Somehow elasticsearch is not able to create an index. You can check the permission of files. Especially in /data folder

Comment: @MusabDogan everything has permission for full Read/Write/Access

Comment: Without seeing logs it's hard to say anything

Comment: @MusabDogan what would u like me to post, where are the logs located?